Difference: think something + [adj VS to be adj]
As far as I'm concerned, the following structures mean the exact same thing:


think/consider/account + O + adj/N
think/consider/account + O + to be + adj/N


Is that true, or is there a difference of some sort, e.g. regarding formality?
P.S. Examples in dictionaries:


In English law a person is accounted innocent until they are proved guilty.
The event was accounted a success.
They will take any steps they consider necessary.
She thought him kind and generous.



Could you give an example where all three verbs would be interchangeable, please? "I think/consider/account music to be healing"? The version with "account" is weird.

@Mari-LouA - 'account' is severely old-fashioned OED entry: 6.III.6 trans. To reckon, estimate, value, hold (a thing to be so and so). First entry 1377, last 1865. Practically the same definition is included in those for 'count', as well: To esteem, account, reckon, consider, regard, hold (a thing) to be (so and so), with a similar date range.

Will you please Post at least two or three  examples of real sentences, found in the wild'?

@Mari-LouA Robbie Goodwin  Yes, I've added some examples.

Formal, and perhaps, slightly old fashioned:
I think Michael [to be] a fool.
I consider Michael [to be] a fool.
I believe Michael [to be] a fool.
I have shown the words 'to be' in square brackets because they are optional.
Modern, suitable for formal and informal use:
I think/believe Michael is a fool.
Using 'consider' as the verb is more formal. Using 'account' or 'count' is very old-fashioned or archaic, and should be avoided.

I'm learning to write academic essays. Are the first three structures suitable? I mean I want to sound formal, but "old-fashioned" doesn't sound so good.

@AnIELTSLearner -they are OK for essays, but perhaps a bit stiff and Victorian for hanging out with your homies.

Thank you! What about "account"? Too old-fashioned even for essays?

@AnIELTSLearner - unless you are pretending it is sometime between 1800 and 1899.
